# How to use R ggplot2 to create a stacked histogram as barcode plot with row-wise color pattern from a R base table

Tags: python, r, ggplot2, matrix, plot

This question has been posted originally [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64121862/how-to-use-r-base-plot-to-create-a-stacked-histogram-as-barcode-plot-with-row-wi) and did not found a solution yet.

Here I would like to ask for ANY solution to the coloring problem while keeping the overall plot layout, possibly using ggplot2 or other ways.

Briefly, I want to plot sth similar to a barcode plot, with bar height reflecting row-wise column differences and bar width reflecting row sums across columns.

```
test.matrix <- matrix(c(70, 120, 65, 140, 13, 68, 46, 294, 52, 410), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
rownames(test.matrix) <- c("BC.1", "BC.2", "GC", "MO", "EB")
colnames(test.matrix) <- c("12m","3m")
test.matrix <- as.table(test.matrix)

test.matrix
     12m  3m
BC.1  70 120
BC.2  65 140
GC    13  68
MO    46 294
EB    52 410

plot(test.matrix)
```

[layout_NO_color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYzDo.jpg)

This is exactly the layout I need, however I cannot figure a way to color the different rows across colums, it only colors columns across rows.

```
color.ct <- c("gold","yellowgreen","navy","royalblue","orangered")
names(x = color.ct) <- rownames(test.matrix)
color.ct
         BC.1          BC.2            GC            MO            EB 
       "gold" "yellowgreen"        "navy"   "royalblue"   "orangered" 
plot(test.matrix, col= color.ct)
```

[layout_color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjxOD.jpg)

Is there ANY R or python solution out there to solve this problem and obtain exactly the same plot layout as above but with bars colored according to the provided color vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this approach with `ggplot2` and `tidyverse` functions:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
test.matrix %>% as.data.frame.matrix %>% rownames_to_column('Var') %>%
  pivot_longer(-Var) %>%
  mutate(name=factor(name,levels = rev(unique(name)),ordered = T)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=name,y=value,fill=Var))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity',color='black',position='fill')+
  coord_flip()+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('BC.1'="gold",'BC.2'="yellowgreen",
                             'GC'="navy",'MO'="royalblue",'EB'="orangered"))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank())
```

Output:

[image]

Another option can be:

```
#Code 2
test.matrix %>% as.data.frame.matrix %>% rownames_to_column('Var') %>%
  pivot_longer(-Var) %>%
  mutate(name=factor(name,levels = rev(unique(name)),ordered = T)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=name,y=value,fill=Var))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity',color='black')+
  coord_flip()+
  facet_wrap(name~.,scales = 'free',strip.position = 'left',ncol = 1)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('BC.1'="gold",'BC.2'="yellowgreen",
                             'GC'="navy",'MO'="royalblue",'EB'="orangered"))+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank())
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is close to what I need, but the column-to-column differences are not displayed anymore with this code.

Comment: @fuchsdeluxe Let me add another possible solution.

Comment: @fuchsdeluxe I have added an update. I hope that can be useful!

Comment: That is definitely useful, Thx a lot! Is there a way to adjust the x-scale, so that it is the same scale for both facets?

Comment: @fuchsdeluxe Yes, just remove the `scales = 'free'` from `facet_wrap()` and you will have a common scale. I hope that helps you!